# Java synchronize propertys of objects of the same class

Tags: java

I have got a DAO e.g.

```
public class Foo {
   private final int ID;
   private String text;
   private String title;

   public void refresh() {
      Foo refreshedFoo=Database.getInstance().getFooById(ID);
      // *** Problem here ***
    }
   // ... Getters and setters for all fields
}
```

Sometimes I need to update all fields of a DAO (refresh it from DB). So how to set all propertys of `this` to the corresponding values of `refreshedFoo`, without writing an assignment for each property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use some library (probably based on reflection) to do the same thing there is no other way to assign each property other than, well, assigning each property.

The alternative is to use the new instance `refreshedFoo` and throw away the old one, if that is possible for your application. Maybe you can have a ProxyFoo that just contains a pointer to a Foo that can be switched on refresh?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways, One way to implement `Clonable` interface and call `clone()` method and second create a constructor that get Foo Object as param and assign the value, so each time you call that object.

And place refresh method in FOODAO  another class, and FOO is model object so should not have refresh method. In this way problem will be solved

Comment: I both cases, you have to still manually write the assignments, though.

Comment: @Thilo no, Object.clone() copies all fields from one Object to another

Comment: Yes Sean is right, yo don't to manual asignment , here is sample URl: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=344

Comment: Okay, but if you clone() refreshedFoo into yet another instance clonedFoo, how does this solve the problem? Same with the copy-constructor.

Comment: show should separate this method from model Foo class to FOODAO class

Comment: You are right. Simplest solution is to place refresh in another object. However, Thilo was first with this idea so I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to do that except for using some black magic reflection hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use assignment for each property. If you do not intend to do it manually, you can use any available libraries for the same such as Apache commons has provided a class BeanUtils. It has got a method copyProperties. You can use that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ORM such as hibernate to avoid manually writing the code.  Or with spring there is row mapper, which reduces the need for such code.

The only other way would be to use the dark side of the force : reflection.

Comment: It seems that `Database.getInstance().getFooById()` is already some sort of ORM.

Comment: @Thilo oh yeah, so there is already an up to date foo why does the OP require another one then. If for some reason it is requried just do as zaffargachal says.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [copyProperties](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) from apache commons beanutils.